# I know why phototaxis happens but why did those bees die?

Tags: entomology, death, species

There is a tube light in front of my veranda. This is just spring. So at night when I turn on the tube light many bees gather around the tube for phototaxis. But in the morning I see many of them are lying dead on the floor.

**Why does this happen?**

Comment: Are you sure they are **bees**? You should post a picture of the insect that you are talking about. Some insects actually have a short adult lifespan.